# Is it possible to convert APFS to HFS+

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I'm deciding to install MacOS High Sierra on my Mac this autumn.So if I find APFS not useful can I convert it back to HFS+ via terminal or using Disk utility?

Comment: I don’t think so. APFS does shallow cloning, which is not available on HFS+, so you will run out of space if you convert backwards.

Comment: APFS also isn’t something you will find immediately useful, it is a OS-level feature, which you wouldn’t use directly anyway

Comment: On the contrary, iOS upgrades did do this in the past, converting to APFS and back. But it could very well backup the file system structure and just restore it.

Comment: I'm thinking of installing high Sierra without APFS because I won't encrypt my disk or use any of the features in APFS.The only reason I am installing high Sierra is because of security and nice features

Comment: @ShaneHsu The iOS file system is dramatically simpler that macOS. No fusion drives, FileVault differences, third party kernel extensions and drivers and API are entirely in a different category. We should [chat] about the iOS test migrations in case they are relevant here. Too much detail for a comment unless you wanted to make a proper answer explaining your findings and thinking.

Comment: "I won't use any of the features in APFS". The main 'feature' of APFS is improving the speed and safety of pretty much every disk operation your Mac performs. You don't need to use your computer any differently from today to benefit.

Comment: Given that APFS is replacing HFS+, not just being offered as an alternative, you should have a much higher bar than "not useful" to switch back. Unless APFS is actively harmful, you should stick with it.

Comment: I'm thinking if I stick with APFS will I encounter some problem.If so what are the problems?And I've also heard that some apps don't work well of at all with APFS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This autumn of 2017 when High Sierra is released, there will be far more concrete details and evidence for you to make an educated decision. I can’t conceive Apple won’t make clear the risks and benefits on consumer, support, professional and technical levels for APFS. My guess is most people should make one backup and then jump. If you have old software that cannot be updated, you might wait three months for any odd bugs to get documented or worked out if you can’t easily recover from a bootable backup or reinstall your apps at the versions you require.

At worst, you can always wipe and reinstall High Sierra on HFS and then copy files from your backup (whether the backup is HFS or APFS or some other file system)

---

In July 2017, The migration scripts and functions are still being tested in beta - so today, there are no signs you could revert back from APFS to HFS on the beta macOS. Worse, you shouldn’t even trust the forward conversion yet for non-throwaway system test use.

Many programs will not work yet on APFS formatted volumes.

- https://bombich.com/blog/2017/07/07/pondering-conversion-from-hfs-apfs

I would recommend keeping all your important data and all your system backups clean and untouched by beta versions of APFS scripts.

What seems to work well even now in the beta is copying files back from APFS to HFS if I work on a file or photo in beta and want to keep it on my main system. That’s a very different thing than reverting the entire file system structure, though.

Comment: I always wait for months and then install a new OS like how I installed Sierra after a week or month

Comment: Sounds good. See you November or thereabouts?  @Geek

Answer (score 0):

I can actually revert to HFS+ (losing my data). I got some help from the following website.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html

Screenshot:

[image]